# NPT pipe thread. $L_3$ vs. $L_2-L_1$

Tags: mechanical-engineering

The standard "ASME B1.20.1 Pipe threads, general purpose", NPT thread section includes these two lengths:

- $L_3$ = length of thread beyond $L_1$ (which is the length of hand-tight engagement between internal and external threads) allowing wrench tight engagement, internal thread (also, wrench make-up).
- $L_2-L_1$ = wrench make-up threads.

Given a physical male and a female thread, how you would measure (measuring procedure) each of them in practice using the definition?

Note, based on the table included in the same standard, these two lengths are basically identical for small diameters, but for large diameters $L_2-L_1$ becomes much larger than $L_3$.

Comment: Put them together hand-tight and then wrench tight.  I would use a master plumber who has calibrated hands for such things, and not just an engineer who knows how to use a pipe wrench (like me).  The extending part of calipers would make measurements easy and repeatable.

Comment: thanks, but what would be the measuring procedure for each of the two dimensions listed above (practically). I am asking this to really understand what they mean and their difference.